# Different icons for different versions

Tags: android, icons

Is it possible to use different icons for ICS devices and 3.0 and previous devices?

When creating custom icons, I created some with 2.3 style, only to see they contrast with other system icons that I use, which are version dependant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the icons in different folders with the API level as suffix like this:

```
drawable-hdpi-v9
```

[Check the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) for more on this method of specifying resources.